# drf-social-oauth2: request.user is AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to use [drf-social-oauth2](https://drf-social-oauth2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html) for authentication and authorization. I set it up using the documentation linked above. But the documentation is lacking. I could not find find how to change certain settings in the documentation.

When I send request to `/auth/token/`, this is the response I get:

```json
{
    "access_token": "KQP6l5nHezWlFO3Ixwz4IIFNUjkvEp",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write",
    "refresh_token": "rmyOZJPQE6Z1eqbpihr2Ux6YMDN1LU"
}
```

But I want to use JWT with custom claims and I cannot find how to do it in the documentation linked above.

My question for now is that how can I use JWT instead of Bearer. And how can I include custom claims in the JWT tokens using drf-social-oauth2 ?

If you can, please point me towards a documentation with more details about drf-social-oauth2. The only thing I found to customize the token is [this](https://drf-social-oauth2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html) in this documentation.

**EDIT 1**

I managed to use JWT tokens by adding `ACTIVATE_JWT = True` in my `settings.py` file. I also managed to include custom claims in the token by overriding the `create_token_response` function of the `TokenView` class and overriding the `auth/token` endpoint as shown below:

```py
from drf_social_oauth2.views import TokenView
import json
from jose import jwt
from django.conf import settings

class CustomTokenView(TokenView):
    def create_token_response(self, request):
        response_data = super().create_token_response(request)
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print(request.user)
        print(request.user.id)
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        url, headers, body, status = response_data
        token_data = json.loads(body)
        access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(
            access_token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"]
        )
        decoded_token["custom_claim"] = "custom_value"
        updated_access_token = jwt.encode(
            decoded_token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm="HS256"
        )
        token_data["access_token"] = updated_access_token
        modified_body = json.dumps(token_data)
        return url, headers, modified_body, status
```

And in urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from drf_spectacular.views import SpectacularAPIView, SpectacularSwaggerView
from account.views import CustomTokenView

urlpatterns = [
    # oauth
    path("auth/token/", CustomTokenView.as_view(), name="token_obtain"),
    path("auth/", include("drf_social_oauth2.urls", namespace="drf")),
    # admin
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # user account
    path("api/account/", include("account.urls", namespace="account")),
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace="rest_framework")),
    # api schema
    path("api/schema/", SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name="schema"),
    path(
        "api/schema/docs/",
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="schema"),
        name="swagger-ui",
    ),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But now I want to include user information in the jwt token. But when I print `request.user` and `request.user.id` in the `create_token_response` function mentioned above as shown below:

```py
print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
print(request.user)
print(request.user.id)
print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

the output is:

```bash
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
AnonymousUser
None
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The user is `AnonymousUser` and the id is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I did what I wanted to do by doing something like this:

```py
import json
from jose import jwt
from django.conf import settings
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken


class CustomTokenView(TokenView):
    def create_token_response(self, request):
        response_data = super().create_token_response(request)

        url, headers, body, status = response_data
        if status == 400:
            return response_data

        # Extract token
        token_data = json.loads(body)
        access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
        access_token_object = AccessToken.objects.get(token=access_token)

        # Extract the email from the request and get the user with that email
        user_email = access_token_object.user
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)

        # Decode the token and add custom claims and encode the token again
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(
            access_token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"]
        )
        decoded_token["token_type"] = "access"
        decoded_token["user_id"] = user.id
        decoded_token["email"] = user.email
        decoded_token["exp"] = access_token_object.expires
        updated_access_token = jwt.encode(
            decoded_token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm="HS256"
        )

        # Update the token with new tokens containing custom claims
        token_data["access_token"] = updated_access_token
        modified_body = json.dumps(token_data)
        response_data = url, headers, modified_body, status
        return response_data
```

and overriding the `auth/token/` endpoint to use this custom view:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from drf_spectacular.views import SpectacularAPIView, SpectacularSwaggerView
from account.views import CustomTokenView

urlpatterns = [
    # oauth
    path("auth/token/", CustomTokenView.as_view(), name="token_obtain"),
    path("auth/", include("drf_social_oauth2.urls", namespace="drf")),
    # admin
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # user account
    path("api/account/", include("account.urls", namespace="account")),
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace="rest_framework")),
    # api schema
    path("api/schema/", SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name="schema"),
    path(
        "api/schema/docs/",
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="schema"),
        name="swagger-ui",
    ),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**EDIT**

This does not work completely. The jwt token sent to the frontend through the api request is modified and it contains the added custom claims. But the jwt token saved in the database that can be viewed from django admin is not modified and does not contain the added custom claims. So, the token sent to the frontend and saved in the database are different. So when I send a request to backend with the token sent to the frontend, it does not work.

What I ended up doing is the following:

```py
class CustomTokenView(TokenView):
    def create_token_response(self, request):
        response_data = super().create_token_response(request)

        url, headers, body, status = response_data
        if status == 400:
            return response_data

        # Extract token
        token_data = json.loads(body)
        access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
        access_token_object = AccessToken.objects.get(token=access_token)

        # Get the user associated with the token
        user_email = access_token_object.user
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)

        # Add more data to the response
        token_data["expiry_time"] = access_token_object.expires.isoformat()
        token_data["user_email"] = user.email
        token_data["user_id"] = user.id

        # Convert into json and return
        modified_body = json.dumps(token_data)
        response_data = url, headers, modified_body, status
        return response_data
```

When I do this and override the `/auth/token` endpoint to use this `CustomTokenView`, then the response I get is something like this:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6InlZdWdqTWw3TFFNTHdqMVdJNEhZMEUyV3c0cTVoWSJ9.sVydaed2xEZ-UjxC3wzoYJcEN7onGndWbRyCXB71aso",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6InFxQk1yclhCR2cxOTZiaU9Yb3pSd1JLT25HTFR1eiJ9.pGWbvTMg490vnt9e8bE3vmsS5HZjjNKDzfyxw8-KaAg",
    "expiry_time": "2024-03-19T12:13:21.481446+00:00",
    "user_email": "company9@gmail.com",
    "user_id": 14
}
```

I store all the information that I require in the localstorage.

If anyone knows how to send all this information by encoding it in the jwt token itself using `drf-social-oauth2`, please guide me.